# Why doesn't MPMoviePlayerController respondToSelector thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

Below is some code I am compiling using XCode 3.2.4 with SDK 4.1:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaUrl];

if (![moviePlayerController respondsToSelector:@selector(thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:)])
    NSLog(@"Does not respond to selector thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:");
```

The output is:

> Does not respond to selector thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:

However, if I don't do the check at all and just call the method, it works just fine.  I'm baffled, any ideas why this would be the case on a device running 4.1?

Comment: Have you tried to copy/paste the exact method name which is wokring into your `@selector`? Maybe a weird typo... I can't see one.

Comment: Just a strange idea,... can you print the 'value' of `moviePlayerController` in your log? Just to be sure it isn't nil at that moment.

Comment: I DID do a copy and paste in case there was a weird typo.  Nope.  And printing the value shows that no, it is NOT nil.  Can you (or anyone reading this) test this on your environment?  I'm still totally baffled, and I've already reinstalled all apps to no avail.